# WooCommerce: Add CSS class to HTML elements returned by function in filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm trying to change this function so the price ex. and inc. TAX get a class, so it is possible to style them:

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-prices-inc-and-ex-tax/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix','bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax', 99, 4 );
   
function bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax( $suffix, $product, $price, $qty )
{
    $suffix = ' <small>ex. TAX</small> - ' 
              . wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ) 
              . ' <small>inc. TAX</small>';
    return $suffix;
}
```

Comment: Stuff you can actually read is sooo much easier to debug, now the change should be obvious

Comment: Like changing `<small>` to `<small class="someclass">` ?

Comment: not only the text but also the prices

Comment: it will be enough to add another class to price_including_tax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole thing into another element

```php
function bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax( $suffix, $product, $price, $qty )
{
    $suffix = '<span class="price_including_tax">'
            . '<small>ex. TAX</small> - ' 
            . wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ) 
            . '<small>inc. TAX</small>'
            . '</span>';
    return $suffix;
}
```

And in your css:

```css
.price_including_tax { color: green }
```

Comment: not only the text but also the prices, so it will be enough to add another class to price_including_tax

Comment: Seems I missunderstood your question. Check my updated answer.